# Do I need to run my AngularJS app code or will it be called by AngularJS if I use ng-app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have seen the following:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    // Module name is handy for logging
    var id = 'app';

    // Create the module and define its dependencies.
    var app = angular.module('app', [
    ]);

    app.run(['$q', '$rootScope',
        function ($q, $rootScope) {

        }]);
})();
```

I've also seen this without the (function () ... ()

Is there any advantage in doing the way it's done above ?

Comment: i dont think there is any added advantage with above implementation of yours

Comment: [`Module.run()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#run) doesn't run the app, it runs the parameter function when the injector is done loading all modules.

Comment: @Blackhole.  I think your reply does not really answer the question. I am asking if the () that's at the end of this function declaration is even required at all. I have seen examples of this so I'm wondering if it is needed. Thank you.

Comment: Of course it is! Otherwise, the content of the function is never called, and then the module `app` never defined!

Comment: using closure you can control the scope of javascript variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of a couple of advantages (but I am pretty sure there are more):

1. **[Immediately Invoked Function Expressions (IIFE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)** are good (among other things) for not "poluting" the global object (e.g. window).
   Any variable defined inside the IIFE will not be available outside (unless explicitely made available).
   (In some cases you might need to access the app from other scripts. You can expose it like this: `window.someApp = app;`)
2. You can "safely" use **[strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode)** (`'use strict'`) ! (This reason should be enough on its own.)
   "Safely" means that you can use `strict mode` locally without the danger of breaking other scripts (e.g. third party libraries, modules from other devs) that are not `strict mode`-compliant.
   If you were to use `'use strict'` outside of an IIFE, any code sharing the same JS context (e.g. other scripts (either inline or external)) would be affected (not to mention JSHint would be complaining as well :)).

Comment: If the function is immediately invoked then what happens if I use the bootstrapping that is run with ng-app. Will this mean it gets run twice ?

Comment: Neither `angular.module()` nor `angular.run()` bootstrap the application. No there will be no double bootstraping (in fact there will be any difference in that regard).

Answer (score 0):

Following may be helpful to you.

it will run automatically with ng-app. it is kind of bootstarpper.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/ce669edfa14dc7eb7c389d2f82c9c98399a9009b/docs/content/guide/module.ngdoc

Here's the calling order:

app.config()

app.run()

directive's compile functions (if they are found in the dom)

app.controller()

directive's link functions (again if found)

You are using javascirpt closure above, which use to manage variables scope.

you can read more about closure here.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

On syntax this is how coded in one of my application.

```
(function (window, angular, toastr) {
    'use strict';

app.run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$window', '$auth',
        function($rootScope, $location, $window, $auth) {
    }]);
     })(window, angular, toastr);
```

Comment: So do you still need the ng-app? Won't it mean it is run twice ?

Comment: @marifemac not twice, however, it will give you leverage to implement logic which should be run on angularjs app start. it is similar to asp.net application_start event in global.asax.cs

Answer (score 0):

I think the code above is just meant to create an IIFE, that is, an Immediately Invoked Function Expression, meant to exploit Javascript's function scoping. In short, is a common javascript design pattern meant to place code inside a local scope. You can read more here:

[Wikipedia entry for IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

I could also copy/paste some explanation for you from books and websites, but I think it's better if you read the original sources to understand IIFEs. I found this article to be very helpful when I learned the concept:

[I love my IIFE](http://gregfranko.com/blog/i-love-my-iife/)

Answer (score 0):

**`run()` - manual bootstrapping :**

- Usefull when you need to delay angularjs loading or when you want to explicitely bootstrap it at a certain time. Example : in a phonegap application, you need to wait for the device to have loaded phonegap API before bootstrapping angular (which is already loaded in the Webview). Usefull also when you need to run a script before angular gets loaded.
- Usefull when you need to run multiple angular application on the same page. You can't use `ng-app` tag in this case and must bootstrap both manually (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp)

Concerning the (function () {}); syntax, as previously said, it's a common practice to encapsulate code in a local scope (with all its advantages like securing own code, avoid conflicts, not polluting global scope, etc).

**`Ng-app` - automatic bootstrap :**

When you have no pre-requisite before loading angular and you can let angular load automatically when browser loads page DOM (DOMContentLoaded) and encounters the `ng-app` app

***You must choose one of the methods, never both at the same time.***

More informations : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap